# How can I create a simple svg triangle through .ts file of angular4?

Tags: angular, svg

I want to create a simple triangle through the .ts file of my Angular project. Currently I am using an svg image through its path in my .ts file. But I am not able to apply fill property for that saved image.
  So I want to create a separate svg triangle in my .ts file not in my html file. Can any one please help me to solve my this issue.
  Please create a simple triangle on this stack blitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-van3zw.
  Any type of help any one can.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Renderer2` for that, except you have to set namespace of svg to do that:

```
@ViewChild('svgContainer') container: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

ngOnInit() {
    const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    const path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(path, 'd', 'M0 50 L100 0 L100 100 Z');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(path, 'fill', 'pink');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(path, 'transform', 'rotate(30, 50, 50)');
    this.renderer.appendChild(svg, path);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.container.nativeElement, svg);
}
```

And in your template **.html**:

```
<div #svgContainer></div>
```

Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nodrwb?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts

But my opinion is to create it in html and manipulate from ts.
**component.html**

```
<svg>
    <path [attr.d]="path" [attr.fill]="fillColor" [attr.transform]="rotation">
</svg>
```

**component.ts**

```
path = 'M0 50 L100 0 L100 100 Z';
fillColor = 'pink';
angle = 30;
rotation = `rotate(${angle}, 50, 50)`;
```

Comment: Thankyou, but here by default triangle color is black, how can I use fill property in my .ts file, please edit the link.

Comment: @RaziAhmad just added one line this.renderer.setAttribute(path, 'fill', 'pink');

Comment: @ Dmitriy Snitko Thankyou, Also I want to rotate this triangle in different different angles, how can I?

Comment: this.renderer.setAttribute(path, 'transform', 'rotate(30, 50, 50)');

Comment: nodeEnter.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 3px)
            .attr("y", -3px)
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .attr("height", 10px)
            .attr("width", 10px),
@Dmitry Snitko, Actually I already have, rectangle some thing like above, so I need the triangle in the same way. Actually I have to append the same triangle in a node of a tree.

Comment: @RaziAhmad SVG doesn't have special tag for triangle. You have to add it with path.

Comment: @RaziAhmad upvote or accept my answer if it was usefull.